# Running 2 Wordpress instances on a single Apache2 - what's wrong?

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, apache2

I have a working Wordpress installation blog.mydomain.net, `blog.` is an `A` DNS record, Apache config is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.mydomain.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    # some rewrites

    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    php_admin_flag engine off
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php
    suPHP_Engine on
</VirtualHost>
```

The installation resides in a `/var/www/wordpress` directory, owned by the corresponding user, there's `blog` DB, etc.

Then I wanted to create a 2nd Wordpress instance on `stud.mydomain.net` domain. 
I created a new DNS records, new folder `/var/www/stud_site` almost the same as `/var/www/wordpress`, but with a different DB name in `wp-config.php`, created a DB for it, and duplicated the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stud.mydomain.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On

    DocumentRoot /var/www/stud_site
    php_admin_flag engine off
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php
    suPHP_Engine on
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I open http://stud.mydomain.net/wp-admin/install.php, it says Already Installed.

More to say, when I look into the page's source, I see it loaded CSS from the blog.mydomain.net host, like if Apache didn't see the 2nd Virtualhost

Comment: This belongs on webmasters SO, but offhand... have you specified a wildcard NameVirtualHost?

Comment: This is probably not it, but did you restart Apache after the config changes? Also, could it be that stud.mydomain.net new DNS has not propagated to you yet and it falls into some wildcard A record? On a final note, if you don't get answers here you may be better off asking in the more sysadmin-oriented serverfault.com

Comment: thanks for comments. it may be that the record didn't propagate though I was thinking it won't working until then at all. and yes, I restarted apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like this is because of PG4WP plugin issue...